# Uploading and fetching images and videos from database

Tags: file-upload, mern, social-media-like

I am creating a social media platform(like instagram) where user can upload images/videos from their account, and see images/videos uploaded by others, same like instagram. how can i implement this? I am using MERN to create the website but now i am stuck in this part.
i want to know how and where i can upload images and videos(free of cost) and later retrieve them to the website so that user can upload any image/video and can see images/video uploaded by others.

I tried using multer to save it in MongoDB but couldn't do so, and i also tried to use google cloud but to use that i have to pay. i want this to do free of cost if possible(since i am a student, and this is my project).